# Using C++ backend in iOS app

Tags: ios

I am writing an iOS app that uses some machine learning algorithms/image recognition on images. My friends have already written the backend in C++ to the point where it takes as input a picture and outputs the text that we need. Our goal is to have iOS be the front-end in that it takes a picture, passes the picture to the C++ backend, and displays the results.

I have absolutely 0 knowledge of C++. Is there some interface where I can pass the image from the Objective-C to a C++ black box and get the output? Or will I be forced to deal with this Objective-C++ thing and integrate the Objective-C and C++ together?

Comment: So let me get this, you know Objective C but have "absolutely 0 knowledge" in C++? Makes no sense. Yes, you need Objective C++.

Comment: Can the backend exist on its own as pure C++, or does it need to be in Objective-C++?

Comment: Objective C++ can serve as the glue. So there can be C++ code by itself, and you can use Objective C++ as glue between Objective C world and C++.

Comment: There are various method to interface C++ with Objective-C, but you are a fool if you expect to be able to complete this task on your own while keeping your proud 0 knowledge of C++. The best you can do is ask your friend to wrap up a C interface for his library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I actually did this exact same thing for a hackathon. All you have to do is expose an multipartFile endpoint which your iOS app is able to hit. An example would be, lets say your server is on yourapp.herokuapp.com, then your endpoint would be:

```
  yourapp.herokuapp.com/processImage
```

Just perform a POST request to that endpoint with your file and then have your back end process the file. If you're intent on staying in the C++ space, I would recommend using the [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/) for your backend, but your development time will be increased 10x if you just build a [rails application](http://rubyonrails.org/) application which exposes this endpoint, and then invokes your c++ code with the image file as a parameter.

You can read up more about REST [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/)

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's expecting to run it locally on the device

Comment: This is an interesting option as well, never thought of it